# how to create and export camelProxy with apache camel blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, aries

I am using camel-blueprint with aries blueprint in osgi container. My configuration is as follows

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

<c:camelContext>
    <c:proxy id="myProxySender" serviceInterface="com.cmt.gabs.camel.test.MyInterface" serviceUrl="direct:a" />

    <c:route>
        <c:from uri="direct:a" />
        <c:transform>
            <c:simple>Hello ${body}</c:simple>
        </c:transform>
        <c:to uri="log:org.apache.camel.example?level=ERROR" />
    </c:route>
</c:camelContext>
```

When i start the bundle it does not give any error, but the proxy is also not created as a service. Please tell me if i am doing any wrong.

I Want to use Camel Proxy for endpoint **direct:a**

**edit**
Camel version 2.11
OSGI container equinox 3.8

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And what container do you use? Is it Apache Karaf?

Comment: I am using the camel 2.11 and using equinox as OSGI container...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the answer long ago but forgot to respond to it.
The answer is simple i just had to export it as a service.